# jquery not firing in web but working in saved code

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I have this small code which changes div after every 20 seconds. it works if I saved that in a small HTML file. it works if I save the live HTML code and run but it does not fire in the live site.

you can see that every 20 seconds the bar is getting changed but in my live site, it is not changing. live site is here.

https://pushdaddy2.myshopify.com/products/uhjkjhkhk

but if I save the live site code in desktop and launch that code in chrome it works.

https://jsfiddle.net/anamika99/vhmo7ex4/

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var allBoxes = $("div#qab_container").children("div");
  transitionBox(null, allBoxes.first());
//  console.log(allBoxes);
  $("#qab_background1, #qab_background2, #qab_background3, #qab_background4, #qab_background5, #qab_background6").css({
    "height": $("#qab_background").innerHeight()
  });
});


function transitionBox(from, to) {
  function next() {
    var nextTo;
    if (to.is(":last-child")) {
      nextTo = to.closest("#qab_container").children("div").first();
    } else {
      nextTo = to.next();
    }
    to.fadeIn(500, function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        transitionBox(to, nextTo);
        var karreff = 787786766;
        console.log(karreff);
      }, 3000); // 20000 on site
    });
  }

  if (from) {
    from.fadeOut(500, next);
  } else {
    next();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="shopify-section-header" class="shopify-section">
  <div id="qab_container" style="display: block; color: inherit; height: 44px;">

    <div id="qab_background" onclick="qab_button_on_click(event)" style="opacity: 1; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; left: 0px; height: auto; width: 100%; z-index: 99998; position: fixed; cursor: pointer; background-image: url(&quot;https://way2enjoy.com/shopify/1/announcementbar/js/img/bar_background/20170926_cart.png&quot;); top: 0px;">
      <div id="qab_bar" style="text-align: center; margin: 0px; padding: 12px 10px; left: 0px; height: auto; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; border: none; background-color: rgba(5, 175, 242, 0); color: rgb(242, 242, 242); font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px; font-family: Helvetica;">
        <div id="qab_content" style="text-align:center; display: inline-block;"><span id="qab_message" style="color:inherit;">All t-shirts are 15% off </span> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="qab_background1" onclick="qab_button_on_click1(event)" style="opacity: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; left: 0; height: auto; width: 100%; z-index: 1000000; position: relative; cursor: pointer;">
      <div id="qab_bar1" style="text-align: center; margin: 0; padding: 10px; left: 0; height: auto; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; border: none;">
        <div id="qab_content1" style="text-align:center; display: inline-block;">
          <span id="qab_message1" style="color:inherit;">fghghghh hghghhfhhf fhfgf</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see `pushowl browserHandler.getSubscription denied` in the console

Comment: I made you a snippet here. The code runs fine here by the way

Comment: @mplungjan i use same code for other pages and works just fine what is happening here. i am unable to understnad

Comment: @mplungjan i think i have figured out. actually html is being inserted by javascript and when the page loads that time those codes are not there so it is not firing but when i run the loaded code from browser that time all codes are properly loaded. so i have to fire my transition part of code after sometimes so that everything is loaded properly then i am sure it will fire

Answer (score 0):

solved this by triggering the function only when all data are loaded.

we have set the settimeout for allBoxes

earlier what was happening that our javascript code was taking some time to insert in html and before that full code was executing and that time in real there was no data we needed so we set the settimeout of 10 second and then everything was working because in this 10 second everything was in loaded in DOM and we were ready with full data.

here is full code which is working flawlessly

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  setTimeout(function () {
      var allBoxes = $("div#qab_container").children("div");

transitionBox(null, allBoxes.first());
    console.log(allBoxes);
           }, 10000);   




  $("#qab_background1, #qab_background2, #qab_background3, #qab_background4, #qab_background5, #qab_background6").css({"height": $("#qab_background").innerHeight()});
});



function transitionBox(from, to) {
    function next() {
        var nextTo;
        if (to.is(":last-child")) {
            nextTo = to.closest("#qab_container").children("div").first();
        } else {
            nextTo = to.next();
        }
        to.fadeIn(500, function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                transitionBox(to, nextTo);
                var karreff=787786766;
                console.log(karreff);
            }, 20000);
        });
    }

    if (from) {
        from.fadeOut(500, next);
    } else {
        next();
    }
}
```